# qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" even though it was found

Tags: qt, qt5, ubuntu-20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 and trying some QT-based apps. In my particular use case, I am trying to launch android file transfer and it throws me the following error:

```
    Failed to create wl_display (No such file or directory)
    qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" even though it was found.
    This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
    Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

This is the output from 'qmake --version'

```
    QMake version 3.1
    Using Qt version 5.9.7 in /home/*****/anaconda3/lib
```

And this is what I get after deactivating conda:

```
   QMake version 3.1
   Using Qt version 5.12.8 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Also, I tried doing :

```
    QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
```

This is the output from ' android-file-transfer export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1'

```
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms" ...
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
    Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
    {
"IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
"MetaData": {
    "Keys": [
        "eglfs"
    ]
},
"archreq": 0,
"className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
"debug": false,
"version": 330752}


    Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
    Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
    {
"IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
"MetaData": {
    "Keys": [
        "linuxfb"
    ]
},
"archreq": 0,
"className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
"debug": false,
"version": 330752}


    Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
    Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
    {
"IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
"MetaData": {
    "Keys": [
        "minimal"
    ]
},
"archreq": 0,
"className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
"debug": false,
"version": 330752}


    Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
    Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
    {
"IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
"MetaData": {
    "Keys": [
        "minimalegl"
    ]
},
"archreq": 0,
"className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
"debug": false,
"version": 330752}


    Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
    Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
    {
"IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
"MetaData": {
    "Keys": [
        "offscreen"
    ]
},
"archreq": 0,
"className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
"debug": false,
"version": 330752}


    Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
    Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
    {
"IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
"MetaData": {
    "Keys": [
        "vnc"
    ]
},
"archreq": 0,
"className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
"debug": false,
"version": 330752}


    Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so"
    Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so, metadata=
    {
"IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
"MetaData": {
    "Keys": [
        "wayland-egl"
    ]
},
"archreq": 0,
"className": "QWaylandEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
"debug": false,
"version": 330752}


    Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-egl")
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
    Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so, metadata=
    {
"IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
"MetaData": {
    "Keys": [
        "wayland"
    ]
},
"archreq": 0,
"className": "QWaylandIntegrationPlugin",
"debug": false,
"version": 330752}


    Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland")
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so"
    Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so, metadata=
    {
"IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
"MetaData": {
    "Keys": [
        "wayland-xcomposite-egl"
    ]
},
"archreq": 0,
"className": "QWaylandXCompositeEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
"debug": false,
"version": 330752}


    Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-egl")
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so"
    Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so, metadata=
    {
"IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
"MetaData": {
    "Keys": [
        "wayland-xcomposite-glx"
    ]
},
"archreq": 0,
"className": "QWaylandXCompositeGlxPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
"debug": false,
"version": 330752}


    Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-glx")
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
    Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
    {
"IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
"MetaData": {
    "Keys": [
        "xcb"
    ]
},
"archreq": 0,
"className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
"debug": false,
"version": 330752}


    Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
    QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
    loaded library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
    Failed to create wl_display (No such file or directory)
    qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" even though it was found.
    This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

    Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

This issue is affecting many other GUI of applications I am trying to use and any solutions would be welcome.

Comment: Got this also on ubuntu 20.04 once. The reason were unexpected cpu loads during startup because of buggy self written code. So maybe there is some wild signal firing going on in your app?

Comment: @ary, did you find the root cause and how to fix it?

Comment: Sadly haven't been able to really solve the problem but  have found a workaround. If I login ubuntu using 'wayland' session, the problem disappears. I use Xorg by default.

Comment: @ary That's not a work-around. That is the solution. If you want to run a wayland application, _i.e._, want Qt to use wayland platform plugin, then wayland display server should be running!! That is possible only when your user session is a wayland session.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause should be debugged with

```bash
$ export QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.qpa.*=true
$ export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
$ export QSG_INFO=1
$ export QT_QPA_EGLFS_DEBUG=1    # or the appropiate
$ ./yourapp -platform wayland
```

There are [more details here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/embedded-linux.html).

Without any other detail, the most probable cause seems to be a device is being pointed at and there is no such file. Such debugging will tell you where it is, and you should note the error then correct it. Other cause might be a missing or wrong `.so` file being pointed.

You could also try `strace` and `ltrace` to find the offending missing file.

Answer (score 2):

Wayland is a communication protocol that specifies the communication between a display server and its clients. Some ubuntu desktop versions already uses Wayland by default but it’s possible to load to Xorg display server instead or anothers.

You can try

```
$ DISABLE_WAYLAND=1 yourProgram
```

Then try to start your program from shell, if it works just change the launcher, fot this you only need to find where program is installed, maybe something like this:

```
$ /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/
```

Edit it with nano (for example) and change the Exec line adding the flag:

```
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/{yourProgram}.desktop DISABLE_WAYLAND=1 /snap/bin/{yourProgram}
```

It works for me, hope it helps!